# How did Voldemort, Bellatrix, and Lucius manage to keep their wands?

Tags: plot-explanation, harry-potter

Voldemort was ripped from his body, Bellatrix and Lucius were given a life sentences in Azkaban. Why did they still have their original wands after beinging restored? Wouldn’t Voldemort’s wand have been destroyed or at least lost among the wreckage of the Potter home? Why wouldn’t Bellatrix’s and Lucius’ wands be snapped upon their convictions? The Ministry threatened Harry with this simply upon being arrested in OotP.

In addition, why would Wormtail need Ollivander to make him a new wand? He blew up the street, cutoff his finger, transformed into a rat, disappeared into the sewer, then took up a 12 year lazy residence with a wizard family. Does he leave it among his remains for identification? But if he did that, Priori Incantatem would show Wormtail’s wand as the guilty wand, not Sirius’, wouldn’t it?

Comment: It's possible that, after the escape from Azkaban, Voldemort helped Bellatrix and the other Death eaters retrieve their wands from someplace in the ministry of magic...

Answer (score 1):

Typically in real life, prisoners have their belongings stored at the prison, or returned to the next of kin.  Either case leaves it easy for them to get their wands back.

Wormtail loses his wand at some point after his mass murder, [it is not specified when](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Peter_Pettigrew%27s_wand).

[Voldemort's wand was recovered by Wormtail](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4493/how-did-voldemort-get-his-wand-back).  It is not specified whether this happens immediately after the Voldemort's fall or later. He was likely already nearby since he was the secret keeper, he could have easily been the first one on the scene after the spell backfired.

Comment: First, thank y’all for the replies. Second, if the Ministry of Magic was decided on snapping Harry’s wand for performing a Patronus infront of Dudley, does it really make sense they’d decide an imprisoned Deatheater’s wand needed to be stored at the Ministry or Azkaban? Crouch Sr. is specifically described as being incredibly hard on Deatheaters, authorizing the use of Unforgivable Curses against them, even encouraging leathal takedowns. The difference in response between a soft threat (Harry, even if he was lying), and a hard threat (Deatheaters) is, at this pint, inexplicable to me.

Comment: As for Voldemort, would it be more plausible for his wand to have been destroyed when the killing curse rebounded upon him? It destroyed his body and the house, but kept the epicenter intact? If so, I suppose it is absolutely possible Wormtail found it before anyone else, even if he did not look until after PoA.

Comment: As for Wormtail’s wand, if he didn’t lose it after his first transformation, what would be a plausible explanation for him assuming his human form again before PoA?

Comment: Remember, Sirius was able to transform at will between human and a dog while in Azkaban.  He did not require a wand.  The person is the source of magic, the wand is merely and instrument of channeling it.  Wormtail may have required the wand to do so, his abilities were mediocre.

Comment: JKR is the one that said Wormtail recovered Voldemorts wand...perhaps he abandoned his own thinking Voldemort's wand would make him a better wizard.

Comment: The only 2 cases where they ever discuss breaking a wand were both children, Hagrid and Harry.  Though when you think about it, both cases were politically motivated.  Hagrid had the stigma of being half giant, many thought he should never have had a wand to begin with (like Umbridge).

Comment: That solves Voldemort for me, thank you. I hadn’t found the post-DH Q&A before now. As for Wormtail, I do remember an Animagus do not require a wand to transform, and I apologize for not being clear. It has been shown throughout the books and movies that Animagus retain their clothes, wands, etc, when they transform. So if Wormtail had his wand on him when he escaped Sirius, his wand should’ve been safely on his person until he was forced back to human form by Sirius and Lupin. Regarding the prisoners, you’ve got a point. I don’t like it, but I can’t dispute it.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. Well the case of Voldemorts wand is solved. Pettigrew must have sneaked it out from Godric's Hollow after his masters defeat.

That leaves Lucius and Bellatrix. Well given that Lucius is a well established rich persona in the Ministry itself. He probably had no issues in getting back his wand using his influence. After escaping he could have bribed someone or adopted other vile plans.

Conjecture: Bellatrix was a hardcore criminal. Perhaps at the time of her arrest she had no wand on her. That's why she got caught at a sticky situation. Even if she was arrested with wand intact the Dark Lord could have obviously made efforts to retrieve the wand of a faithful servant. After all he made regular visits to the Department  of Mysteries without even being seen.

As regards wands being broken, going by the movies, only two students were threatened with that - Harry and Hagrid. Harry received the warning while Hagrid suffered the punishment owing to rearing Acromantulas and accusation of a murder. Other than that, even Dumbledore went to Azkaban in Chamber of Secrets. His wand wasn't snapped.

Conjecture : While being chased by Sirius wormtail might have done what follows. He perhaps caught Sirius unarmed. Remember Sirius isn't the most patient person. When he saw no sign of struggle at Wormtail's house, he gave chase in a hurry. So he might have forgotten his wand. Pettigrew blew up the street and left the wand at the site before transforming into the rat. The ministry never thought to cross check the wand given the magnitude of the crime. (Similar to when Winky was found with a wand and they didn't check whose it was) They arrested Sirius immediately with the wand. Voldemort wouldn't have bothered taking the pain to retrieve Wormtails wand. He was a bit faithless. Hence Peter needed a new wand.

Citing Winkys arrest, Priori Incantatem showed the spell last performed not who performed it. So Wormtail couldn't be caught by that. Hope this helps.

Comment: Voldemort’s Wand: Agreed, Rowling confirmed this in an interview, which I was led to via an answer to this question.     Lucius’s Wand: It makes no sense that Lucius would’ve retained any influence at the Ministry after being captured as a Deatheater within the Ministry.     Bellatrix’s Wand: She was captured after Voldemort’s fall, so he’d have been useless. That being said, it was explicitly stated that Voldemort could not enter the Ministry without making himself know. If he could, he wouldn’t have need months of scheming just to fail at forcing another to retrieve the prophecy.

Comment: Wormtail’s Wand: Suggesting any wizard, much less a warrior in times of war, would simply forget their wand at home is ludicrous. Even more so in the case of Sirius Black. Agreed the Priori Incantatem only shows the what, not who; if Wormtail’s wand was left at the scene, it simply increases the gross negligence of the authorities. Going back to wizards not going about without their wands, Wormtail was a coward. His wand his protection and weapon. He might not be good with it, but he’d need abandon it, even if doing would aid in the faking of his death.

Comment: Lucius's Wand : Well, that's not true. The Ministry was already corrupt. Only Voldemort's appearance confirmed it. And they couldn't go on arresting people just because they were once associated with Voldemort. Malfoy was caught in the duel red-handed so they had no choice. After Rufus Scrimegeour died, they took over so easily probably because of that. I'm sure one of them was involved. How else would you explain it?

Comment: Bellatrix's wand: It doesn't matter when she was captured. It matters when she was released. She served her sentence bit and was released only after Voldemort returned. So thats what I'm saying. Voldemort perhaps made sure she was out of Azkaban and with wand intact after coming back.

Comment: Wormtail's wand: Its true Sirius might have been armed. I am sorry i had to stretch a bit. Well, how about this.. Sirius was armed indeed. Wormtail cast the spell, blew things up, planted Sirius there with his wand. Now his wand was probably lying nearby. So it is obvious that a mass murder would never be performed with a criminals own wand. He would take some other wand to avoid Priori Incantatem. So the Aurors thought Sirius threw it away after casting the spell. Which makes it more fitting now.

Comment: Like you said. Wormtail was a coward. Reason enough he fled the scene. Though his wand was his protection..it no longer was *after* casting an 11-murder spell. It could be traced back to him. So he had to get rid of it. It makes sense. We can never say he was unintelligent. I'd rather say he was the most intelligent of the four Marauders. Which is why he was able to do his duties on both sides of the law. That's why he must have figured out that living as a pet rat was most beneficial to him as he had no wand.

Comment: Regarding Voldemort *himself* fetching wands. I was clearly making bizzare possibilities. Well, given that he is the Dark Lord, he'd just ask a minion to fetch it for him. Please note all of this is ONLY a conjecture. None of it is mentioned even slightly in the movies. All i want is for you to get a decent answer, my friend.

Comment: Bellatrix’s Wand: No more how it’s sliced, I am having trouble accepting the Ministry wouldn’t have snapped her wand. Lucius’s Wand: I can accept this as a possibility, but it’s very thin in my opinion. Wormtail’s Wand: His intelligence is an interesting point, but I’d argue more to his survival instincts and adaptability. He is shown to be intellectually lacking at least twice in the books as a student; once as a spoken memory, once as a visual. That being said, it makes sense he’d leave his wand to securely fake his death, but he was going into hiding from other Deatheaters, hence my doubt.

Comment: I do appreciate your thoughts, amd apologize if I feel anything but friendly.